# Getting group name from account in Stormpath-Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug, stormpath

I am making a Stormpath-Express application for a company configured with many groups. Each group can only see certain elements on the page (ie. admins can delete and approve posts, users can only create and edit them). Is it possible to use Jade to create a conditional that will display the component by getting the user's group membership?

Here's a rough example to show what I mean:

```
if user.admin === true
    a.btn.submit Approve Post
else 
    p Please wait for management to approve
```

I have noticed I can use `user.fullName`, `user.email`, etc. but not `user.directory`.

I have also tried this through the server side using getDirectory method

```
client.getDirectory(href, function(err, dir) {
    console.log(dir);
});
```

However, this is from the Node docs, and breaks when applied to my Express project. Any help with this is greatly appreciated since I'm in a deadline!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much thanks to rdegges answer, I had to modify with the version 1.0.5 express-stormpath because the groups property is used to store the uri to retrieve the groups...

```
app.get('/page', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  req.user.groupsNames = [];

  req.user.getGroups(function(err, groups) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    groups.each(function(group, cb) {
      req.user.groupsNames.push(group.name);
      cb();
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      return res.render('myview');
    });
  });
});
```

And the jade template looks like...

```
- if (user.groupNames.indexOf('admin') > -1)
  a.btn.submit Approve Post
- else
  p Please wait for management to approve
```

Comment: Jade gives me an error telling me that "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". Why is this? I've revised that my group name is indeed admin, so why is it 'undefined'?

Answer (score 1):

Heyo -- I'm the author of the express-stormpath library, figured I'd hop in here.

I'm actually going to be adding in some new ways to do this in the near future -- but for now, what you can do is pre-load a user's groups into an array, then check membership.  Here's an example:

```
app.get('/page', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  req.user.groups = [];

  req.user.getGroups(function(err, groups) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    groups.each(function(group, cb) {
      req.user.groups.push(group);
      cb();
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      return res.render('myview');
    });
  });
});
```

Now that you've defined `req.user.groups`, you can then use this in your Jade template, like so:

```
- if (user.groups.indexOf('admin') > -1)
  a.btn.submit Approve Post
- else
  p Please wait for management to approve
```

Comment: I keep getting an error for the line `var req.user.groups = [];` , it declares the "." in req.user as an unexpected token for a variable. Is there another way to declare it? thanks!

Comment: Whoops -- I had a typo, it should say `req.user.groups = [];` and it should NOT start with `var`, my bad!

Comment: @rdegges. Can you please tell how to store the user groups when the session is started for the user instead of querying for groups in every action?

Comment: @user2458203 you'd have to do some caching -- use something like Redis or Memcached and pull it out =)

Comment: @rdegges - Is this still the correct way to get groups from a req.user object? When I inspect the groups value all I see is a href with a url